# splitting a list of integers to 2 lists: one of positive numbers and the other of negative numbers - haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I split a list of integers to 2 lists: one of positive numbers and the other of negative numbers  ?

this is my attempt:

is it possible to do it ?

```
split:: [Int]->[[Int]]
split [] =[[]]
split xs =[x|x<-xs, x<0]:[y|y<-xs, x>=0]
```

my second try:

```
split:: [Int]->([Int],[Int])
split [] =([],[])
split xs = ([x|x<-xs,x<0],[y|y<-xs,y>=0])
```

somehow I am still not getting the correct result.

when I run

```
   split [1,2-2,3-4]
```

I got

```
   ([-1],[1,0])
```

Comment: Your new code has the wrong results because you left out the comma before each of the negative numbers, so you are subtracting from the previous value instead.

Comment: so how will you write it differently ?

Comment: I meant that your test case is wrong, not the code itself. Try `[1,2,-2,3,-4]`

Comment: thanks.. I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the [`partition`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v%3apartition) function:

```
import Data.List

split = partition (>=0)
```

Your attempt has a few problems. Firstly you need to parenthesise the `x:xs` pattern otherwise it will be parsed as `(split x):xs` which is not what you meant. Secondly, it will produce a type error because the `:` operator on the right-hand side should be given a single element as its left argument and a list of those elements as its right argument, but you have given it a list as both arguments. Finally since you only want to return two lists, you should use a tuple for the return type, not a nested list.

Comment: Then you can try to fix your version. I've explained what's wrong with it.

Comment: is this the correct declaration ? split:: [Int]->([Int],[int])